# getBytes() working with ResultSet but not CachedRowSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, cachedrowset

I have a Derby SQL database in which I have a table containing a blob field that needs to contain a serialized object.
I access it through JDBC.
The problem is that when I de-serialize the object using a ResultSet all works fine, but if I use a CachedRowSet I get a "Data Type Mismatch" Exception.

Here is the bit of code that works:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
byte[] buf = rs.getBytes("albero");
```

Here is the alternative bit tha

```
CachedRowSet crs = null;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
crs.populate(rs);
crs.next();    
byte[] buf = crs.getBytes("albero");
```

Could anyone help me understand why this different behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: `crs.nextPage()` before `crs.next()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CachedRowSet` (assuming the reference implementation `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`) stores a copy of the data in the `ResultSet` within the cached rowset. It does this using the `getObject` method of the result set provided to `populate`.

As you indicate that the column is a blob, I assume that `getObject` will return a `Blob` and the column type in metadata is `BLOB` and not a byte array (type `VARBINARY` or `LONGVARBINARY`). Therefor the cached rowset will only allow you to retrieve the column as a `Blob`, and not as a `byte[]` even if the original result set supports that.

The JDBC 4.2 specification (Appendix B.6) describes which methods are supported for which types, and for a `BLOB`, only `getBlob` (and `getObject`) are to be supported. However contrary to requirements in the specification a lot of drivers are more lenient and also support `getBytes` and `getBinaryStream` for `BLOB`. In this regard, the `CachedRowSetImpl` is more strict in its interpretation of JDBC.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed reply. I have resolved using getBlob().getBytes()